# to insert new values in sql db..by selecting different tables from combo box

Tags: c#, sql-server

well I have made this program to insert new values in SQL db,by choosing between different tables from combo box.I need to change the sql query by which I can use insert command individually for each table in combo box...the area where i need help is in bold ...

```
namespace combo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List lstNewRows = new List();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void PopulateComboBox()
        {
            try
            {

                List _items = new List();

                _items.Add("select * from lol");
                _items.Add("select * from datejoin");
                comboBox1.DataSource = _items;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateComboBox();
        }

        private void PopulateGridView(string connString, string sqlQuery)
        {

            String strconnetcion = connString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconnetcion);



            try
            {

                con.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

                sqlCmd.Connection = con;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                PopulateGridView(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void InsertInfo()
        {

            string connectionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string value1 = "";
            string value2 = "";
            connectionString = @"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            foreach (int rowIndex in lstNewRows)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value != null)
                {

                    value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    value2 = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    ***string sql = "insert into lol (name,marks) values('" + value1 + "','" + value2 + "')";***
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Row inserted !! ");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            InsertInfo();

        }

        private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            lstNewRows.Add(e.Row.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no bold text.

Comment: I'm not clear on your problem and there is no bold text. Are you trying to call one set of SQL that will insert into different tables depending on parameters? Or use the C# code to call different SQL depending on parameters?

Comment: Tom.Bowen89 sorry the satement is between *

Comment: well i want to use the C# code to call different SQL depending on parameters...plz help

Comment: I think this is supposed to be the bold text : `***string sql = "insert into lol (name,marks) values('" + value1 + "','" + value2 + "')";***`

Comment: andri-yes ur write dats the line i wanted in bold...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the source, I understand what you are trying to accomplish. I will give my answer your problem first, but please read the recommendations after the answer because proceeding in the way you are onto now this application may end up as a big headache to whoever is going to maintain it.

**Answer**:

```
Change your items to be as follows:
List _items = new List();
_items.Add("lol"); // removing select * from 
_items.Add("datejoin"); // removing select * from 
comboBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

Now in your `PopulateGridView` function you can change the `sqlQuery` to

```
private void PopulateGridView(string connString, string sqlQuery) {
    sqlQuery = "select * from "+sqlQuery;
```

then in your `InsertInfo` function you can do the following (at the location where you are defining the string sql variable):

```
string sql = string.Empty;
switch(comboBox1.SelectedValue) {
    case "lol":
        sql = "insert into lol (name,marks) values('" + value1 + "','" + value2 + "')";
        break;
    case "datejoin":
        sql = "insert into datejoin (..."; // fill in the column and values as needed
        break;
}
```

**Recommendations**:

1. Please change your vanilla string queries to stored procedures or look into LINQ
2. Do not use `select *`, always try to mention the column names in a select query
3. Provide a more user friendly name in the combobox than the table name, it is not always safe to make the table names so obvious to the end user
4. Try using a separate data access layer and move the database specific codes into that layer